# How can I read the current directory from a 7-zip SFX, to copy one file there after installing to another one?

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating an application that needs to be copied at a certain fixed directory but one file needs to be copied at the directory from which the SFX was run.

I was not able to do this. I've created with a .bat and using FOR to read a file I wrote to by calling to SET from the SFX execution.
But it's always related to the install directory.

So, to be clear, what I need to do is:

1. Copy all files from the SFX to a directory
2. Move one of these files to the directory from which the SFX was executed

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to create an installer for this. A self-extracting archive won't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If, as an example, your application SFX would be called `myapp.exe`, then you could do the following in batch (assuming I have understood your problem correctly):

```
@ECHO OFF
:: configure: directory where to install application
SET DSTDIR=D:\program files\my app
:: configure: which installed file to move back to installer directory
SET MOVEFILE=lang\ast.txt
:: %~dp0 is expanded to where we (the batch) currently are
SET SRCDIR=%~dp0
:: call 7-zip self-extractor with destination directory (1)
myapp.exe -o"%DSTDIR%"
:: move the special file back (2)
MOVE "%DSTDIR%\%MOVEFILE%" "%SRCDIR%"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The problem is that I don't know where exactly the user will be running the SFX. So, I need to have the user execute the SFX unpacker/installer, which should read somehow where it was executed, copy files to a certain directory and then move one of those files to the original directory where it was executed.
The problem is that with 7-zip SFXs I can't copy to different directories with the same package.
Thanks!

Comment: @user2723297 This solution is correct as long as user do not install from `myapp.exe`, but from this install batch.